# Xml to java with axis

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, axis

I have a Web Application that calls some remote web-services. The client side (Java class) is generated by Axis 1.3 starting from a WSDL (WSDL2Java in Eclipse) and it consumes correctly the XML message (SOAP) exchanged with the remote server.

Now I have some XML responses (saved on filesystem) of one of those Web Services but I need to bind this XML to the Java class, in order to use the data contained. 
How can I do this? How can I bind the XML (with Axis) in order to populate the already existing Java bean?

Is it correct to use

```
org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer desrializer = dc.getDeserializerForClass(ExampleClass.class);
```

Thanks
messo

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer server = new org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer();
server.setOption(AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, false);
MessageContext msgContext = new MessageContext(server);
java.io.Reader reader = new java.io.StringReader(txt.toString());
DeserializationContext dser = new DeserializationContext(new org.xml.sax.InputSource(reader),msgContext,org.apache.axis.Message.RESPONSE);
dser.parse();
SOAPEnvelope env = dser.getEnvelope();
RPCElement rpcElem = (RPCElement)env.getFirstBody();
MessageElement struct = rpcElem.getRealElement();
Object obj = struct.getValueAsType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://xmlns.eu/prova"),eu.myClass.class);
```

Now I have an object that contains the correct fields (with values).
But I have a problem with the deserialization on an Array.
If the XML deserialized contains an array and so I change the last line above in this way

```
Object obj = struct.getValueAsType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://xmlns.eu/prova"),eu.myClass[].class);
```

I receive this error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: No deserializer for {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType
```

How can I resolve?

Thanks